# Testing if model is audited without RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, acts-as-audited

I use audited gem to audit all changes on my models. In gem specification (https://www.rubydoc.info/github/collectiveidea/audited/Audited/RspecMatchers) we can find info how to test it with use of RSpec, i.e:

```
it { should be_audited }
it { should be_audited.associated_with(:user) }
```

I would like to do similar tests but without RSpec - any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if it `respond_to?` certain methods that come along with audited gem.
like

```
User.respond_to?(:audited)
# or
User.respond_to?(:audits)
```

Also you could use  `auditing_enabled` option from the readme.

```
User.auditing_enabled
```

This returns in default true when audited is there.

The same for associated audits. Just build a data structure for you relation and check of the audits are equal your expected results.
Take this example from the audited readme for example:

```
company = Company.create!(name: "Collective Idea")
user = company.users.create!(name: "Steve")
user.update_attribute!(name: "Steve Richert")
user.audits.last.associated # => #<Company name: "Collective Idea">
company.associated_audits.last.auditable # => #<User name: "Steve Richert">
```

There you can then easily check if the associated audits look like you want it.